# specify folder name during copy data task

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a Copy Data task that extracts a set of compressed files from an "http file" source task.

This Copy Data task uses an Azure Blob Storage linked connection that writes to a specific folder:
[blob link picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hL9Lh.png)

The issue I'm running into is that this connection seems to create another folder beneath the path that the connection writes to with a GUID that appears to generate off the RunID for the [task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R15nM.png).

How do I specify what folder I want it to go to instead of writing to a random GUID?  I have another set of copy data tasks that's trying to look for the unzipped files in a folder but it can't find them each time because the GUID is always going to be different.

Thanks all.

Comment: Issue is not at the Destination.  What process are you using to extract zip?

Comment: I'm not actually doing anything to deflate the zip, it seems to do it on its own? It's the intended behavior but I don't see anything anywhere that I specified anything to actually unzip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, I think you could configure folder path dymatically in your blob storage dataset.

For example:

```
"folderPath": {
          "value": "@concat('test1/',
                    formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy'),'-', 
                    formatDateTime(utcnow(),'MM'),'-',
                    formatDateTime(utcnow(),'dd'))",
           "type": "Expression"
}
```

Then your files would be copied into `'yyyy-mm-dd'` folder which could be found by your another activity.

[image]

Comment: OK, this is what I was thinking but where exactly do I enter this code update? Within the blob connection dataset?

Comment: @TimF In blob dataset, you could view the json code by clicking top right button.

Comment: OK, I'll give this a shot and see if it does what I want.

Comment: @TimF Sure,waiting for your reply!

Comment: so instead of the section of JSON saying:
"typeProperties": {
            "fileName": "",
            "folderPath": "timtesting"
        }
It should say:
"typeProperties": {
            "fileName": "",
            "folderPath": {
          "value": "@concat('timtesting/',
                    formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy'),'-', 
                    formatDateTime(utcnow(),'MM'),'-',
                    formatDateTime(utcnow(),'dd'))",
           "type": "Expression"
}
        }

Comment: forgive the comment formatting, trying to figure out how to make it not look awful

Comment: I get how this would work but when I try to validate the code it says "invalid characters are found"?

Comment: Not sure why it wasn't working still but you got me started on the right path to get it fixed.  Cheers!

Comment: @TimF Please try to remove `"fileName": ""` ?

Answer (score 0):

Please don't set copy behavior. Then it will use the zip file name as the folder name. [image]

Comment: it's already set to not have any copy behavior for that sink?